# Return value of istream::get()

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This question is about the member function of `basic_istream`:

```
int_type get();
```

as described by N3337 27.7.2.3#4  (that is [istream.unformatted]). Presumably the actual Standard text is the same.

The text says:

> After constructing a sentry object, extracts a character `c`, if one is available
>
> *Returns:* `c` if available, otherwise `traits::eof()`

This text suggests that negative `char`s should return a negative value. We could compare with the next section, `basic_istream<charT,traits>& get(char_type &c)`, which says:

> After constructing a sentry object, extracts a character, if one is available, and assigns it to `c`.

This is very similar wording to `get()`.

However, when I try `get()`, negative chars return a positive value; i.e. `basic_istream::get()`  behaves like the C function `getchar()`. This would be the sensible behaviour (to allow signalling of EOF), however the Standard text does not seem to specify this.  The C99 description of `getchar()` and friends specifically says that it returns the value *converted to an unsigned char*. But `basic_istream::get()` does not have any equivalant text.

My question is: is `get()` meant to be specified to return a value in the range `0...UCHAR_MAX` union `EOF`? Or should it return the actual `char` converted to `int_type` (via implicit conversion)? Or something else? What exactly does and does not the Standard specify here?

If "something else", how do I transform the result of `int i = cin.get()` to match the char value read by `char ch; cin.get(ch);` for the same input character?

Comment: I'm assuming that your question is why `basic_istream::get()` lacks this detail in its description, but formally you're not asking a question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt updated to actually ask a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear up your confusion, the difference just doesn't matter. Think about what you can or can't do with the returnvalue of parameterless `get()`. The funny thing is that you can't reliably compare it to `EOF` or `traits_type::eof()`, because it's not ever guaranteed to be equality-comparable (it **is** for builtin `char` and `wchar_t` though). In order to compare it correctly, you just use `traits_type::eq_int_type()`. Similarly, in order to extract a character from it after checking for EOF, you use `traits_type::to_char_type()`, and that function then converts the type accordingly. Similarly, `get()` can't use the implicit conversion but has to use `traits_type::to_int_type()`.

In summary, the guarantee for `getchar()` that it returns the "unsigned" value or EOF is not necessary, since the `traits_type` encapsulates this knowledge and should be used for correct code.

Example use of parameterless istream::get():

```
traits_type::int_type c = in.get();
if(traits_type::not_eof(c))
    my_string += traits_type::to_char_type(c);
```

Similar use of single-parameter istream::get():

```
traits_type::char_type c;
in.get(c);
if(in) // check for EOF or other input failure
    my_string += c;
```

Comment: Can you post a code sample demonstrating the code to transform the result of `std::cin.get()` to match the value that `ch` would get from `std::cin.get(ch)` ?

Comment: Typically those sources are pretty open as they are still inline and not compiled. Anyhow, I'll try to add an example...

Comment: It's just that I tried it and got a mismatch so it'd be good to look at something authoritative before posting my attempt :)

Comment: I hope the two examples clear up the differences, I didn't compile them though.

Comment: thanks; my test works correctly now (actually it worked right the first time but I had my terminal doing UTF-8 when I wasn't expecting it)

Answer (score 2):

As per [char.traits.typedefs]

> `typedef INT_T int_type;`
>
> Requires: For a certain character container type `char_type`, a related
>   container type `INT_T` shall be a type or class which can represent all
>   of the valid characters converted from the corresponding `char_-type`
>   values, as well as an end-of-file value, `eof()`. The type `int_type`
>   represents a character container type which can hold end-of-file to be
>   used as a return type of the iostream class member functions.

The only requirement by the standard is that `int_type` is large enough to hold all of the values of `char_type` (it doesn't even have to be a fundamental type), plus the value returned by `eof()`, the standard also requires however that `char_traits<char>::int_type` is `int`, and that `char_traits<wchar_t>` is `wint_t`.

The reason you are seeing your `char`s cast to an unsigned value is because GCC is making sure that `EOF` and the character value `0xff` are distinct behind the scenes in `char_traits<char>::to_int_type` by casting the character to `unsigned char` before returning the `int` (note that the standard also requires that `char_traits<char>::eof` returns `EOF`, and `WEOF` for `wchar_t`). Without the cast `0xff` would be sign extended to the equivalent of `EOF`, at least for GCC.

As for casting (even implicitly) the return value of `get` to a `char`, this works for GCC due to the way it handles [signed conversion](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation).

> The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a
>   signed integer type when the value cannot be represented in an object
>   of that type (C90 6.2.1.2, C99 and C11 6.3.1.3).
>
> For conversion to a
>   type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2^N to be within range of
>   the type; no signal is raised.

This isn't portable however, and you should be using `traits_type::to_char_type` on the return value first (after checking for `EOF` / `eof()` of course...).

Comment: On my g++ 4.8.3, `std::istream::int_type` appears to be `int`. The text you quote doesn't seem to specify how the `char_type` characters are converted to `int_type`; is it stated somewhere that it is the same as for `getchar()` or are there other possibilities?

Comment: @MattMcNabb `std::istream::int_type` should be `typedef`ed to `traits_type::int_type`, which for my 4.9.0 is `unsigned long`. As for the conversion the standard doesn't seem to care, only that as Ulrich says aside from `char` and `wchar` you cannot safely use the return values from `get()` for direct comparison with the original character type.

Comment: presumably that also implies that the return value cannot be stored in a character array or pushed onto a string, etc. ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb forgot to reply sorry, I've made a big edit to my answer after ruminating over the standard.

Comment: thanks for the update, good answer. I have clarified in my post now that I was actually assigning the result to `int` , avoiding that char conversion issue (although as you pointed out this should be `traits_type::int_type`, not `int`).